# Waiting for tornado future to complete

Tags: python, tornado

I have a function that returns a future. I want to create a decorator to the function which waits for the future to complete and then return the result essentially converting the async function to blocking function (which I will use in my REST API). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: [`run_sync`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html?highlight=run_sync#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.run_sync)?

Comment: Post the code of your function to get better answers.

Answer (score 4):

```
def sync(fn):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return IOLoop.instance().run_sync(lambda: fn(*args, **kwargs))

    return wrapped

@gen.coroutine
def my_coro():
    # ...

sync_fn = sync(my_coro)
result = sync_fn()
```

Comment: The problem is if `fn` itself calls another function decorated by `@sync` an error will occur `RuntimeError: IOLoop is already running
` can you tell me some workaround?

Comment: At this point I think you must consider seriously whether you are solving the right problem. If you don't want your code to be async, why is it written with coroutines? If you do want it to be async, why do you want to use this decorator?

Comment: I am using an aync library(there is no alternative) but i want my code to be sync for REST api.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve a future you need to `yield` it. Something like this might work:

```
from tornado import gen    

def blocking(func):
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        result = yield func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return gen.coroutine(new_func)
```

Comment: Python version < 3.3. do not allow 'return' with argument inside generator.